# Bash executing a subset of lines in script

Tags: file, bash, sh

I have a file which contains commands similar to:

```
cat /home/ptay89/test/01.out
cat /home/ptay89/testing/02.out
...
```

But I only want a few of them executing. For example, if I only want to see the output files ending in 1.out, I can do this:

```
cat commands | grep 1.out | sh
```

However, I get the following output for each of the lines in the commands file:

```
: cannot be loaded - no such file or directoryst/01.out
```

When I copy and past the commands I want from the file directly, it works fine. Are there better ways of doing this?

Comment: Works for me here. Some weird characters in your file i think.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have spurious carriage returns in your file (created under Windows?). Use `tr` instead of `cat` to remove them:

```
tr -d '\015' <commands | grep 1.out | sh
```

Comment: Almost +1, but `tr` does not take a file name as an argument.  I think you mean: `tr -d '\015' < commands | ...`

Comment: @WilliamPursell thank you for spotting this. Edited to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a

```
grep -e '^cat.*out' commands | grep 1.out | sh
```

That should ignore any weird characters and take only the ones you need.

Comment: @tripleee +1, although you probably mean “win” instead of looke.